# Unable to set variable type in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, types, variable-types

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$array = array ('1','2','3','4');
```

And I want to add parts of given string (even it consists of numbers) to the array if it isn't already exist in array. For example, if the given string is `1234`, it should add `12` , `23` and `34`. I wrote simple code for it like this:

```
$string = '1234';
$string_length = 4;
$array = array ('1','2','3','4');
for($i=0;$i<$string_length-1;$i++){
    $element = substr($string,$i,2);
    if (!in_array($element, $array)){
        array_push($array, $element);
    }
}
```

It works well when I try `1234` as `$string`. But when I try `1024` as `$string`, it returns the array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 24
)
```

As you see, after  `[4] => 10`, there must be `[5] => 02`, but there isn't it.

The cause is `02` is equal to `2` *(which is in first given array)* as a integer. That's why the code skipped it. But I need to add it.

For solving problem I set the type of `$element` as a `string`. So I added `settype($element,'string');` after `$string_length` in my code, but nothing changed.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
if (!in_array($element, $array, true)){
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:
Notice I am passing `true` to the in_array function. It does a strict comparison.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
$string = '1024';
$string_length = 4;
$array = array ('1','2','3','4');
for($i=0;$i<$string_length-1;$i++){
    $element = substr($string,$i,2);
    if (!in_array($element, $array, true)){
        array_push($array, $element);
    }
}
```